# Is it possible to detect vs version during NuGet package installation?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I would like to detect which in which version of VS is my NuGet package being installed. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect the Visual Studio version using PowerShell. JQuery uses this technique to show a warning if the Visual Studio version does not support intellisense files for JavaScript. In JQuery's NuGet package there is an install.ps1 script that has the following PowerShell:

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

# VS 11 and above supports the new intellisense JS files
$vsVersion = [System.Version]::Parse($dte.Version)
$supportsJsIntelliSenseFile = $vsVersion.Major -ge 11

if (-not $supportsJsIntelliSenseFile) {
    $displayVersion = $vsVersion.Major
    Write-Host "IntelliSense JS files are not supported by your version of Visual     Studio: $displayVersion"
    exit
}
```